# How to dismiss UIPopover from a button in the Popover with IOS 8 XCode 6 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I managed to display popover using `UIPopoverPresentationController` as the `UIPopoverController` got deprecated in IOS 8, but now I want to dismiss the popover on tap of button from the popover.

How can it be dismissed?

Answer (score 8):

Use presentingViewController property of the UIViewController to dismiss.
Eg: To present

```
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
  vc.preferredContentSize  = aPreffferedSize;
  UIPopoverPresentationController *popcontroller = vc.popoverPresentationController;
  popcontroller.barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
  popcontroller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
  popcontroller.delegate = self;

  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To dismiss programatically,

```
  [[vc presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will work although there is one small error in it. It needs to be [[vc presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 2):

I am using

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

in the button's IBAction in similar scenario.

Comment: Are you positive that it gets called? Does it fail quietly or with an error?